# Mason not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, mason

I'm using [Mason](https://github.com/DrewDahlman/Mason) on my website. Everything is working fine, except IE8 (who would've guessed?).

The error it returns:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property '1': object is null or undefined.
```

The line this error is triggered:

```
if( w >= settings.columns[colsCount][1]){
```

The colsCount returns '4' when the error occurs. When I test this in other browsers it only returns 3 max. I have tried to do minus 1, but that would give errors on multiple other lines.

I tested the demo that is included in the zipfile when you download it on Github, and even that one is failing in IE8. I have reported this issue as you can see on the Github, but I'd like to ask you guys for a quick solution, since my deadline for this project is quite soon.

I have tried multiple grids to achieve what I want, so trying another one like Masonry and Isotope is out of the question. (They don't provide what the client wants).

Thanks for looking in to this!

Comment: If count is count indeed, that is common mistake, array[array.length] will always be out of bound because index is zero-based.

Comment: I know that, there already is a -1 in the code tho, before this line of code. `colsCount = settings.columns.length - 1;`

Comment: There is a bug in demo. Actually, in all of it. Take a look at `sizes: [ [1,1], [1,2], [2,2], ],` That last comma after `[2,2]` is deal-breaker. IE8 expects next element. Remove it and demo works.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I was already checking for commas in my code but never thought of the array-in-array. Thanks! :-)

Comment: You can always post this as an answer if you want, I'll accept it :)

Comment: Note that after `layout: "fluid"` there is another useless comma, but it looks like in object is not so crucial. This was unexpected for me too.

Comment: @HMR posted answer while we discussed here. You can accept it, so future visitors will easy to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the fluid page there are several script errors with trailing comma's: `layout: 'fluid'` had an extra comma that causes a script error and sizes

```
var sizes= [
                    [1,1],
                    [1,2],
                    [2,2],
                ]
console.log(sizes.length)//=3 in ff and 4 in IE
```

No need to change the library but change the calling code.